# python - JSON object could not be decoded

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, tweepy

I was trying to mine twitter data using tweepy and the data loaded into a JSON file , however the following code :

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json

consumer_key = '****'
consumer_secret = '****'
access_token = '****'
access_secret = '****'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

f = open('twitterdata.json', 'a+')

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(10):
        json.dump(status._json, f)

line = f.readline()
tweet = json.loads(line)
print json.dumps(tweet, indent = 4)
```

produces the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytwittermine.py", line 21, in <module>
    tweet = json.loads(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested in one of the answers I now add a newline in every iteration of the `for` loop , so the code now is :

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json

consumer_key = '****'
consumer_secret = '****'
access_token = '****'
access_secret = '****'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

f = open('twitterdata.json', 'a+')

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(10):
        json.dump(status._json, f)
        f.write('\n')

f.seek(0)
line = f.readline()
tweet = json.loads(line)
print json.dumps(tweet, indent = 4)
```

The above code gives the ValueError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytwittermine.py", line 23, in <module>
    tweet = json.loads(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 3115 - line 2 column 1 (char 3114 - 301245)
```

Comment: Well, what's the first `line` read?

Comment: Can you provide the file that got written?

Comment: it is a pretty big file @StamKaly i can copy its first line(it has 10 line corresponding to 10 iterations)

Comment: Alright, the first line would be enough.

Comment: @StamKaly the first line had 301425 characters and apparently the question details fails to edit

Comment: I made a quick script for you, upload the line [here](http://stamkaly.pythonanywhere.com/json) and then it'll be viewable from [here](http://stamkaly.pythonanywhere.com/json/line)

Answer (score 3):

You write to a file, then read withour rewinding, so nothing gets read. Add `f.seek(0)` between writing and reading.

Comment: It gives the error `ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 3115 - line 1 column 255237 (char 3114 - 255236)` when I add `f.seek(0)` between the `for` loop and `line = f.readline() `

Comment: That is likely because you don't write newlines between `json.dump` invocations; `json.dump` doesn't do it for you, so all your data ends up as a single line.

Comment: so i should write a newline in every iteration?

Comment: after using `f.write("\n")` it still gives the error `ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 3115 - line 2 column 1 (char 3114 - 301245)`